# Once sudo su'd to root, is there a command to see my username?

Tags: linux, rhel, sudo, users

I have sudo rights on a redhat box; once I've `sudo su -` to become root in a shell, are there any commands I can run to see what username I su'd FROM?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The shell's parent process is `su -`, and the parent of that is the `sudo su -`. So you need to find out the user running `sudo su -`'s parent process by searching back in two steps with `ps`:

```
ps -o user= $(ps -o ppid= $(ps -o ppid= $PPID))
```

But you shouldn't be doing `sudo su -` if your version of sudo is not too old to have `sudo -i`. Sudo sets the environment variable `SUDO_USER` to the name of the user who ran sudo. You won't see it with `sudo su -`  because `su -` scrubs the environment.

```
$ sudo -i
# echo $SUDO_USER
gilles
```

Comment: And `sudo -si` gives you a shell with `SUDO_USER` set.

Comment: @bahamat: Just `sudo -i` gives you a shell. In fact: `sudo: you may not specify both the \`-i' and \`-s' options`

Comment: Yes, you're right. That wasn't in the man page, but when executed that's the message that comes out.

Answer (score 4):

Run command `whoami` it will return you something like that:

```
gladimdim tty2        2011-01-27 23:54 (:0)
```

In bold "gladimdim" is the user which was initially logged to system.

Comment: `who am i` is not a command on my system, and `whoami` returns "root"

Comment: On my system it works: `whoami` returns 'root', `who am i` returns my username

Comment: @rubik That's just because it's the `who` command.

Comment: I tried to edit this question to say `whoami` instead of `who am i`. `who am i` is not a reliable solution because it's not installed on many systems by default, so shell scripts may fail. I don't mind if you don't approve the edit though. It's a matter of 'personal preference'.

Answer (score 1):

I think he meant:

```
$ who -am i
```

which could (depending) be parsed the same as:

```
$ who -am
```

The "-a" lists all users currently logged in and "-m" filters that down to only those users (should really be one) who are associated with who's STDIN, which is to say it'll tell you who is logged in at your terminal.  That's what you're looking for.

```
$ who -am
```