# Tracking what commands were executed after sudo to another user

Tags: sudo, monitoring

I have provided `sudo` to ten users to become another user like `nsup`.

I want to track which user executes which command after they become `nsup`.
If there is a way to store the log files in a common file that would be great.

I have tried looking at `/var/log/secure`, but from there I cannot distinguish which user executed which command after they became `nsup`. It shows only which user executed the command to *become* `nsup`, and nothing beyond that.

Comment: That's right, if one uses sudo to open a new shell, actions performed in the shell aren't logged. If there's a way to log them, I don't expect it will be through sudo. And I've never heard of any way to do such logging which aren't "voluntary" (that is, that the user couldn't override). For "voluntary" logging, you could write a script that grabs the latest line from /var/log/secure when a shell starts, and combines that with normal shell history. Or see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6554/once-sudo-sud-to-root-is-there-a-command-to-see-my-username

Comment: There could be flaw too. Consider 2 user logged in sametime and they become nzsup user and start exectuing some command.how to find which user executed which command after sudoed to nzsup.all the command executed will be in history file of nzsup only.

Comment: I was imagining a shell session would just determine at the beginning who the original user was. But yes, there would be a race condition if two users sudoed a new shell right at the same time. The thread I linked to discusses another way to determine who the original user was.

Answer (score 6):

If your users use bash, you can use an /etc/bash.bash_logout script to
save an extra copy of the history in time-stamped format.

For example, I wrote the following to provide an audit-trail of who
did what and when (on a server with multiple sudo users), and also to
preserve history in case the machine was broken into:

```
#! /bin/bash

# /etc/bash.bash_logout
#
# Time-stamped bash history logging
# by Craig Sanders <cas@taz.net.au> 2008
#
# This script is public domain.  Do whatever you want with it.

exec >& /dev/null

# LOGDIR must already exist and must be mode 1777 (same as /tmp)
# put it somewhere easily overlooked by script-kiddies.  /var/log 
# is a bad location because slightly-brighter-than-average SK's will
# often 'rm -rf /var/log' to cover their tracks.
LOGDIR='/var/tmp/.history'

[ -d "$LOGDIR" ] || exit 0

# Get current user name and who they logged in as.
CNAME=$(id -u -n)
LNAME=$(who am i | awk '{print $1}')
NAME="$LNAME--$CNAME"

# Get the TTY
TTY=$(tty)

# get the hostname and ip they logged in from
# short (non-fqdn) hostname:
RHOST_NAME=$(who -m  | awk '{print $5}' | sed -r -e 's/[()]|\..*//g')
# or full hostname:
#RHOST_NAME=$(who -m  | awk '{print $5}' | sed -r -e 's/[()]//g')

# if no RHOST_NAME, then login was on the console.
echo "$RHOST_NAME" | grep -q '[:/]' && RHOST_NAME="console"

# get the IP address
RHOST_IP=$(who -m --ips | awk '{print $5}')
echo "$RHOST_IP" | grep -q '[:/]' && RHOST_IP="console"

RHOST=$(echo "$RHOST_NAME--$RHOST_IP")

WHERE="$RHOST--$TTY"
WHERE=$(echo "$WHERE" | sed -e 's/\//-/g' -e 's/^-//')

# Filenames will be of the form:
# $LOGDIR/cas--root--localhost--127.0.0.1---dev-pts-1
# Ugly, but useful/informative. This example shows I logged in as cas
# from localhost, sudo-ed to root, and my tty was /dev/pts/1
HISTLOG="$LOGDIR/$NAME--$WHERE"


# Optionally rotate HISTLOG on each logout, otherwise new history
# sessions just get appended.
#[ -e "$HISTLOG" ] && savelog -l -c 21 -q $HISTLOG > /dev/null 2>&1

# Log some easily parseable info as a prelude, including the current
# history settings (an unusual HISTFILE or zero HISTSIZE setting is
# suspicious and worthy of investigation)

cat <<__EOF__ >> "$HISTLOG"

### TIME ### $(date +'%a,%Y-%m-%d,%H:%M:%S')
### FROM ### $RHOST_NAME,$RHOST_IP,$TTY
### USER ### $LNAME,$CNAME
### WHOM ### $(who -m)
### HIST ### $HISTFILE,$HISTSIZE

__EOF__


# Setting HISTTIMEFORMAT seems to be buggy. bash man page says it uses
# strftime, but all it seems to care about is whether it's set or not -
# 'history -a' always uses seconds since epoch, regardless of what it is
# set to.

HISTTIMEFORMAT="%s"
history -a "$HISTLOG"


# Now write history as normal (this seems buggy too. bash used to always
# write $HISTFILE anyway, but now it won't do it if you've already run
# 'history -a')

unset HISTTIMEFORMAT
history -w
```

Comment: Which works unless the user sets `HISTFILE=/dev/null`...

Comment: it works regardless of what the user sets HISTFILE to.  that was the whole point of writing it.  read the script, `history -a "$HISTLOG"` appends the history to $HISTLOG.  doesn't use or care about $HISTFILE.

Comment: alternatively, a much simpler version could be put in user nsup's `~/.bash_logout`

Comment: It should be mentioned that this is obviously not a secure log. Use auditing tools if you want secure logging.

Comment: Re "HISTTIMEFORMAT seems to be buggy" - the format is for presentation, not for storage. It is used when you issue for example `history 10`. For storage, HISTTIMEFORMAT only says whether to store timestamps (if set to anything) or not to store at all (if unset). The entries are only stored as %s.

Comment: Where should i install it: `/etc/bash.bash_logout`? Should I then make it executable?

Comment: @cas This works pretty well. However I have noticed that in order for it to work the user you want to track must execute the script. Is there no way to have userA start it and track userB?

Comment: No.  it's a quick and dirty hack for a sysadmin (root) to log what users are doing on a system even when they think they're being clever and setting `HISTFILE=/dev/null`...to save evidence in case an investigation is needed.  It can't be used for one user to snoop on another, and it's not intended for that use.

Comment: as other comments have mentioned, it's not a highly secure auditing solution.  it's meant solely to be useful only in certain situations...e.g. where there's a senior sysadmin and a bunch of junior admins.  If something gets broken, and then you fix it, you can look in the history logs to see who did what and when.  that's a good teaching/mentoring opportunity - you can then ask them about it, why they did it that way, and explain why/how it broke something else, and what better ways there are to do what they tried to do.  which can then be written up on the sysadmins' intranet/wiki.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented in this way.

in `rsyslog.conf` file I have added the below lines to track

```
$umask 0000                 
$FileCreateMode 0666         
local2.info /var/log/usercommands
$umask 0077
```

In the `/etc/skel/.bashrc` file I have added below lines.

```
myname=`who am i | awk '{print $1}'`
PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a >(logger -p local2.info -i "$myname $USER[$PWD] $SSH_CONNECTION")'
```

Hope this might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

> Asked 11 years, 1 month ago

see  https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security_guide/sec-understanding_audit_log_files

that points to RHEL 6 but if that matters then look up the latest *Understanding Audit Log Files* at Redhat.

you want to look at `uid`, and `auid` which is the audit uid, and `euid` which is the effective uid of who started a process.  But to effectively capture this, which would be in `/var/log/audit/audit.log` as a result of `systemctl enable auditd` you need to have a properly defined `/etc/audit/rules.d/audit.rules` file.  For what you ask in the subject line of this post - yes that's all trackable (maybe not easily human readable) but it is there in audit.log... and 11 years ago before RHEL/CentOS 7 was likely not as good as it is today with RHEL 8+ and whatever version of auditd is at today.