# Protect session log from being written again by anyone

Tags: command-line, files, logs, command-history, audit

We have implemented a workaround to save command history in a new file for each user session for audit purpose. So each session file is identified by the start time and the username.

**The problem:** The session user is the file owner, so he is able to modify or even delete it.

Is there a way, once the file is filled, to prevent any change on it ?
It's like *write-once* and it's locked.

Comment: That's what syslog is for.

Comment: Use the `audit `. See http://serverfault.com/a/336234

Answer (score 2):

What you are suggesting is nigh impossible to do properly with standard tools.

As you noticed, saving the command history is usual will not work, since the file will be owned by the user, and they can can delete, clear or edit the file at will. Even if we could work around this, perhaps by making the command history file a pipe read by some trusted process, there's nothing to stop the user from just turning off the history file or pointing it somewhere else.

We could create a new shell with mandatory command logging to prevent that (with the logs sent to another process via a pipe, socket or syslog), but the user could still simply start a normal shell, or a Perl or Python interpreter among other things, to work around the logging. Logging what the subprocesses did, would require wrapping the whole session in `script` or similar to log everything the user sees. Even then there is the possibility of just downloading code and running it, without printing it on the terminal. Preventing the user from running arbitrary programs would do it, but it would also prevent doing most useful things. Preventing running shells or Perl scripts would also prevent many common tools from working.

This result isn't surprising, considering that the shell and other utilities are meant as a tool *for* the user, not *against* them.

Perhaps you could arrange the user's session to be wrapped in `strace` or similar to see every interaction their processes had with the system, but reading the `strace` log from a longish session would not be much fun.

Also, I would think your users would object to this level of monitoring, I know I would.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to write these suggestions, I will consider the "trusted process" one.

Comment: The command history file could be made append-only and placed in a directory owned by root. However, that would not help with auditing since users could switch off history logging or run another shell.

Comment: That piping to a root-owned process idea could be combined with an `/etc/bash.bash_logout` script (which could, e.g. save command history to a file, or into an sql db with at least uid, euid, date, time, and history text  fields).  See my answer to http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49229/tracking-what-commands-were-executed-after-sudo-to-another-user for an example.  It's far from perfect, but it's good enough for casual use.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to give a good answer without knowing more about your
setup, but it sounds like a way to achieve some of your goals,
assuming you use a file system that supports it, such as ext3, would
be to mark the log file "append-only", using `chattr +a <file>`.

Setting or unsetting the attribute requires special privileges, and
then the file can only be appended to. This would not prevent your
users from appending arbitrary data to the file, but it would prevent
them from removing any data that is already there.

Comment: Like you said, this command require special privileges. How to apply chattr on a new file without root intervention ?

Comment: @user619005 You can't. But it's useless anyway: users could easily bypass the command history file (e.g. by turning history off or using another shell).