# getting IP address of red hat users that connected using SU -

Tags: ssh, terminal, su

**TL;DR:**
why on a single server the *who -m* command doesn't provides the output of IP address and the username that initiated the connection to the server

**the Question:**
I have several Linux servers with same OS Dist (RHEL 5.11) . one of the servers was configured by workers very long ago that are not available anymore.

I was trying to implement a sort of History audit for users that connect to a single user with

```
su - <powerful_user>
```

we have no way to prevent them from working like that. but we do want to audit their IP and initial username. I found someones solution for that:
[solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49229/tracking-what-commands-were-executed-after-sudo-to-another-user)

and it works great! the problem is that there is a single server (the most important one) that doesn't allows to get that info when doing

```
su - <powerful_user>    
who -m
```

who -m shows the initial user (the user that connected and used su command) and the IP address of the workstation that opened that session.
that server doesn't show that info. instead after doing su - it's shows the current user and not the one that initiated the session.

I have no idea what makes it so. but this is what I did:

1. compered logon scripts for the powerful user -> they all the same.
2. environment variables -> I found that the working servers get this variables automatically set even after su - :

   SSH_ASKPASS

   SSH_CLIENT

   SSH_CONNECTION

   SSH_TTY

but on the server with the problem its not being forwarded to other sessions that were opened by su -.

3. after seing that it's mainly ssh variables I have checked the ssh configuration, and it's the same as all other servers.

basically it's not clear to me why this server behaves differently.

Comment: Useless solution to copy bash history log on logout. If a bad guy will input `space` before each command, it will not be saved to history log.

Comment: For auditing a Linux system use auditd - https://www.tecmint.com/linux-system-auditing-with-auditd-tool-on-centos-rhel/

Comment: currently it's less important to catch all of the commands. it's more important for us to get the user and his IP address.
the question is why who -m doesn't provide that result

Comment: Could you please post output of the command: `cat /etc/passwd | grep <powerful_user>`

Comment: here it is:
      <powerful_user>:x:601:501::/files/rdbe/<poweful_user>:/bin/bash
     it's the same for other servers

Comment: Is your `su` PAM-enabled? Check both `/etc/pam.d/su` and `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` files - post it somewhere on https://pastebin.ubuntu.com.

Comment: this is the result of /etc/pam.d/su: 
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/XJwcsxH99F/

I don't have common-auth but i have system-auth:
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/kS3sBbcFWq/

Comment: Finally, post your `id` command output. It seems I understand your problem.

Comment: here is the results of id: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/RyGwZNbzVG/
thank you!

Comment: I have posted solution. Has the problem gone away?

Comment: hi,  I checked on the working server, together with all the things you advised me to check:
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/HJJt8bxCVx/
and he also not in the wheel group, also the way we do su is using sudo, we don't have problem to connect to users, the issue is with the lacking output from who -m  command, here is further demonstration:
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/zXryGG8cBs/
any way thank you for the help!

Comment: Command `last` would be way better IMHO

Comment: Kiwy, it's a useful command, but it doesn't allow you to identify your initial connection to the server like who -m does.

Answer (score 1):

As it follows from `/etc/pam.d/su` file only members of `wheel` group have permit to use `su`, since there is line in the file:

```
auth            required        pam_wheel.so use_uid
```

It's necessary to add all of your users to the `wheel` group:

```
usermod -G wheel <powerful_user>
```

Add every user you wish to permit to use `su` in the same way. Reboot your server afterwards to apply changes.

Comment: hi, I checked on the working server, together with all the things you advised me to check: pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/HJJt8bxCVx and he also not in the wheel group, also the way we do su is using sudo, we don't have problem to connect to users, the issue is with the lacking output from who -m command, here is further demonstration: pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/zXryGG8cBs any way.

Comment: @DimitriAvrutin Could you please post output of the command `last -f /var/run/utmp` after logging in as `powerful_user`.

Comment: here:
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/hbxvWph7MX/
there are some other users which are not mine, I did some remarks I hope it's easy to understand.

there is another thing I noticed, going by Auditd logs, it's also says hostname=? for sessions under SU, instead of giving their IP address.

Comment: @DimitriAvrutin More outputs are needed: `cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep UseDNS` and `cat /etc/rsyslog.conf | grep 'auth\|IncludeConfig'`

Comment: here it is:
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/rQYV2xBtkD/

Comment: @DimitriAvrutin Uncomment the line `#UseDNS yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, disable `UseDNS`, i.e. change it to `UseDNS no`, restart ssh server and try again.

Comment: @DimitriAvrutin Let's check additionally `utmpdump /var/run/utmp` and content of the file `/etc/login.defs`